# Exception running a rails 3 app in Phusion-Passenger: undefined method `passenger_tmpdir='

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger

I'm trying to deploy a 3.1.3 app in Phusion Passenger on a Debian system, but I get an exception when I access any page:

```
    *** Exception NoMethodError in spawn manager (undefined method `passenger_tmpdir=' for PhusionPassenger::Utils:Module) (process 15041, thread #<Thread:0x00000001219750>):
            from /usr/lib/phusion_passenger/passenger-spawn-server:57:in `<main>'
    [ pid=14670 file=ext/apache2/Hooks.cpp:727 time=2012-02-26 19:41:33.844 ]:
      Unexpected error in mod_passenger: Cannot spawn application '/usr/local/share/www/the-app-location': The spawn server has exited unexpectedly.
      Backtrace:
         in 'virtual boost::shared_ptr<Passenger::Application::Session> Passenger::ApplicationPoolServer::Client::get(const Passenger::PoolOptions&)' (ApplicationPoolServer.h:471)
         in 'int Hooks::handleRequest(request_rec*)' (Hooks.cpp:523)
```

Googling has turned up nothing. The error looks like a config problem, but I can't find anything which sets `passenger_tmpdir` anywhere.

One feature of the environment which might be relevant: Both ruby 1.8 and 1.9.1 are installed. `/usr/bin/ruby` points at Ruby 1.8.

What is missing?

Comment: No obvious answer. I've ended up using [thin](http://code.macournoyer.com/thin/) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've probably installed passenger as a native package. Installing it via the gem should do the job quite well (it did for me).

Check out the official documentation: http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#_installing_via_the_gem

Comment: It was installed as a native package. I will try to find the time to retest with it installed as a gem only...